# caffe - Input data, train and test set

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

**RAW data dim :**

1) `64 x 45 x 18432` in `.mat` format... ---> Class1

`1 x 18432` in `.mat` format... ---> labels

2) `64 x 45 x 18432` in `.mat` format... ---> Class2

`1 x 18432` in `.mat` format... ---> labels

3) `64 x 45 x 18432` in `.mat` format... ---> Class3

`1 x 18432` in `.mat` format... ---> labels

**How to use/convert it for caffe as a input... using python?**

Comment: `64`-by-`45` is a gray scale image (single channel), for RGB image you need `64`-by-`45`-by-`3`...

Comment: feeding caffe data from matlab through hdf5 should not make any difference. You need to feed the data in dimensions `Batch`-by-`channel`-by-`height`-by-`width`.

Comment: Ok.... That's very helpful.....

Comment: Right now, I am train network with with 2 class data... but accuracy is constant 1 after first iteration !  Why is that happened ?

Comment: this seems to be a new question.

Comment: Ok... I make it new one...